# Livebook failed to start with reason: {:livebook, {:bad_return

Tags: elixir

So I'm trying to run Livebook locally on my macbook.

I first installed it via the Mac installer (dmg).
After it was installed, opening it doesn't do anything.
I spammed it, and then I saw the Livebook icon appear on the top bar (dunno what it's called on mac)

Great, I got it running. Then I close it and can't open it anymore.

So I got frustrated a little bit and decided to just run it locally. I deleted it in the "Application" folder, then follow the instruction in GitHub to install it:

```
mix do local.rebar --force, local.hex --force
mix escript.install hex livebook

# Start the Livebook server
livebook server --name
```

Got an error about hostname. It was in the FAQ so easy fix:

```
livebook server --name livebook@127.0.0.1 --port 51200
```

Got it working now. Great. Then I close the application via `ctrl+C`,
and I can't run it anymore. I feel it's the same issue while ago.

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Livebook] Application running at http://localhost:51200/?token=...
Livebook failed to start with reason: {:livebook, {:bad_return, {{Livebook.Application, :start, [:normal, []]}, {:EXIT, {:function_clause, [{Livebook.Hubs, :to_struct, [%{hub_emoji:
```

I'm not getting any hits in Google.
Would appreciate any help.

Elixir version:
1.14.3-otp-25

Erlang version:
25.3

Comment: What does `elixir -v` returns?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin 

Erlang/OTP 25 
Elixir 1.14.3

installed via asdf-vm

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't open it anymore' when installed through dmg? Spotlight doesn't find it? You can try to go directly into Applications folder, find the LiveBook, double click on it, once it appears on your top bar you can navigate to `http://localhost:64707` or select `Open` directly on the icon itself